# why are the elements of my array changing in this loop?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, shuffle

This is very bizzarre. Every time I run this code, in at least one iteration of the loop, one of the elements of my `shuffled_couples` array is modified, messing up the final output. I have tested this with arrays that were not the product of shuffling `couples_array`, and those arrays seem to be unaffected.

I inserted a number array in the place of `shuffled_couple` inside the loop, and with each iteration, `shuffled_couples` took on one more value from that numbers array, going from left to right:

```
couples_array = [
["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
["Paris", "Helen"],
["Romeo", "Juliet"]
]

shuffled_couples = couples_array.shuffle

couples_array.count.times do |idx|
  puts "before loop #{idx}, shuffled_couples = : #{shuffled_couples}"
  couples_array[idx][1] = shuffled_couples[idx][1]
  puts "after loop #{idx}, shuffled_couples = : #{shuffled_couples}"
  puts
end

puts
puts
puts "The final value of couples_array is #{couples_array}"
```

Before loop 0, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Bonnie"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

After loop 0, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

Before loop 1, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

After loop 1, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

Before loop 2, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

After loop 2, shuffled_couples:

```
[["Paris", "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

The final value of `couples_array` is:

```
[["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Paris", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
```

What is going on here? How can I fix it? I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first *deep* clone your array. That means you have to clone all elememts *in* the array (not only the array itself):

```
shuffled_couples = couples_array.map { |element| element.clone }
shuffled_couples = shuffled_couples.sample
```

Answer (score 1):

It's behaving exactly as you told it to.  You have to remember that with an array of arrays, the outer array actually contains references to the inner array.  Let's look at the implications.

```
irb(main):001:0> couples_array = [
irb(main):002:1* ["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
irb(main):003:1* ["Paris", "Helen"],
irb(main):004:1* ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
irb(main):005:1> ]
=> [["Clyde", "Bonnie"], ["Paris", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
irb(main):006:0> 
irb(main):007:0* shuffled_couples = couples_array.shuffle
=> [["Romeo", "Juliet"], ["Clyde", "Bonnie"], ["Paris", "Helen"]]
```

At this point, `couples_array[0]` and `shuffled_couples[1]` both point to the **same** array, `["Clyde", "Bonnie"]`.  If I alter the second element by coming at it from **either** reference, the change will be visible when accessed/viewed from the other reference. It's exactly the same array, it's just being accessed by two different routes.

```
irb(main):008:0> couples_array[0][1] = 42  # replace "Bonnie" with 42
=> 42
irb(main):009:0> couples_array
=> [["Clyde", 42], ["Paris", "Helen"], ["Romeo", "Juliet"]]
irb(main):010:0> shuffled_couples
=> [["Romeo", "Juliet"], ["Clyde", 42], ["Paris", "Helen"]]
```

In this example, `couples_array[0]` and `shuffled_couples[1]` are exactly the same array, it's just being accessed by two different routes.  If you reshuffled, depending on the luck of the draw you would often get different specific matches, but the underlying concept of what's going on would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make a deep copy of your array. You are pointing both of your arrays at the same instance and so are editing both of them in the loop. If you change your shuffle line to this:

```
shuffled_couples = couples_array.shuffle.clone
```

I think you'll get the results you expect. More on duplicating vs cloning in ruby here:
https://coderwall.com/p/1zflyg/ruby-the-differences-between-dup-clone

Comment: I just gave it a shot, I'm still getting the same results however. I played around with it, making clones of clones and I keep getting the same result!